# TypeListener does not detect Map instance

Tags: java, dependency-injection, java-8, guice

I´m using Guice TypeListener to intercept a map instance generated by a provider.

Here the config method where I bind my listener

```
@Override
public void addConfig() {
    MapListener mapListener = new MapListener();
    requestInjection(mapListener);
    bindListener(Matchers.any(), mapListener);
}
```

This is the map instance created by this provider

```
  @Provides
  Map<String, String> mapTest(){
    return new HashMap<>();
  }
```

This is the listener class to detect the map instance

```
public class MapListener implements TypeListener {

    @Override
    public <I> void hear(final TypeLiteral<I> typeLiteral, TypeEncounter<I> typeEncounter) {
        typeEncounter.register((InjectionListener<I>) i -> {
        if(i.getClass().isAssignableFrom(Map.class)){
              System.out.println("DI:"+ i.getClass()
                                .getName());
             //TODO:Logic to modify map
        }
        });
    }
}
```

The problem is the Map is never passed to the hear method.
Am I doing something wrong?

Regards.

**Solution**

Guice do not filter any instance if has not been instantiated by itself, so instances created by a provider wont be filter.

Comment: What does your injection point look like?

Comment: @DanielPryden Sorry what do you mean?